# Keycloak token verification fails when the backend is running in a Docker container

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am in the early stages of building my web application. I intend to use Keycloak as the identity provider to secure the backend. On my local machine, I am running both Keycloak and my backend as docker containers but on different networks, since eventually in production, I would like to have the authentication server running Keycloak running separately from the backend e.g `account.example.com` and `api.example.com` respectively

Locally, my Keycloak container can be accessed via the base URL `http://localhost:8080/auth` and the backend via `http://test.localhost:8000/`

I have created a client in the Keycloak realm whose access type is confidential. I am generating the token using the authorization code grant type.[image]

Each REST API endpoint on the backend would therefore verify the token passed to the authorization header and then call the Keycloak server to verify the token before processing the request.

The issue that I am currently experiencing is that the token verification fails with the response

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Token verification failed"}'
```

After investigation, apparently, it's because I am calling the Keycloak server from the backend API container. If I generate the token using curl within the backend docker container, the token I receive is being verified fine, but a token generated outside the container is not.

I am using `python-keycloak` as a wrapper for Keycloak REST API

```
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID


self._keycloak = KeycloakOpenID(
            server_url='http://host.docker.internal:8080/auth/',
            realm_name='myrealm',
            client_id='myclient',
            client_secret_key='mysecret,
        )

if "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" not in request.META:
       
        return JsonResponse(
            {"detail": NotAuthenticated.default_detail},
            status=NotAuthenticated.status_code,
        )

 auth_header = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION").split()
 token = auth_header[1] if len(auth_header) == 2 else auth_header[0]

    
    try:
        self.keycloak.userinfo(token)
    except KeycloakInvalidTokenError as e:
        # print(e)
        return JsonResponse(
            {"detail": AuthenticationFailed.default_detail},
            status=AuthenticationFailed.status_code,
        )
```

How do I resolve this and have token verification working on my local machine

Comment: Can you post some details from the Keycloak logs, please.

Comment: Try to set the frontend URL in your Keycloak realm to `http://localhost:8080/` and see if that works.

Comment: @sventorben Thanks alot!!!! It worked. Adding `http://localhost:8080/auth` as the frontend url worked

Comment: @sventorben Maybe you can post your suggestion as an answer then I can approve it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708121/16357334

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your token is invalid, because the issuer (`iss`) in the token does not match the issuer that is expected by your backend service.

Your backend (or an adapter/framework within your backend) will use OIDC discovery protocol to determine the expected issuer. For this, it will call `https://keycloak-container-name/auth/realms/<your-realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration`. This will return metadata like this:

```json
{
  "issuer":"https://keycloak-container-name/auth/realms/<your-realm>",
  ...
}
```

Keycloak will determine the host part of the issuer (`keycloak-container-name` in this case) based on the request. So, if your backend queries the discovery endpoint wiht `keycloak-container-name` from within the docker network, the host part will be `your-container-name`. Your backend will expect the issuer to be `https://keycloak-container-name/auth/realms/<your-realm>` in this case.

Now, if you want to query a token from your frontend, your frontend will send the request to `http://localhost:8080/auth/...`. Since the issuer will be determined based on the request, the issuer in that token will be `https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<your-realm>` in this case.
This does not match the expected issuer `https://keycloak-container-name/auth/realms/<your-realm>` and therefore the token will be rejected as invalid.

You can also verify this by calling the OIDC discovery endpoint via `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<your-realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration`. You will get a response like this:

```json
{
  "issuer":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<your-realm>",
  ...
}
```

To fix this you can set the `Frontend URL` in your realm to `http://localhost:8080/auth`. With this setting the issuer will no longer be determined in the request, but will be fixed `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<your-realm>`.
You can check this from within your backend container by issuing a request to `https://keycloak-container-name/auth/realms/<your-realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration`. This will return metadata like this now:

```json
{
  "issuer":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<your-realm>",
  ...
}
```

If you do not want to configure this for every realm seperately, you may instead configure the [default hostname provider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/16.1/server_installation/#_hostname) server-wide.

Comment: Do you have a public example of this working?   I'm trying to setup a test case for a Wildfly client adapter issue and I ran into this.  Please provide some tips for: https://github.com/slominskir/wfly6000.   Perhaps the issue is "localhost" is an invalid FRONTEND_URL?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like I hit a different bug while troubleshooting a bug.   Using auth-server-url instead of provider-url works (and fixes both bugs).

Comment: I don't know how this is a valid answer... backend can only communicate to KC server using the container name and the token will still be associated to localhost domain (the public domain). So the KC server will continue to reject it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the `issuer` of the token. Issuer of your token from the postman is `http://localhost:8080/...`, but backend is configured to accept only issuer `http://host.docker.internal:8080/...`. It is a best practise to use the same `protocol:domain[:port]` for IdP (Keycloak in your case) everywhere e.g. `https://keycloak.domain.com`, otherwise you will have this kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks @Jan Garaj After doing research I found out that that is an issue. Nevertheless setting the realm frontend url to `http://localhost:8080/auth` solved the issue as suggested by @sventorben

Comment: @theTypan frontend url is not a solution, but only work around. If you have OIDC discovery validation properly implemented (which apparently it is not a case for used backend OIDC lib), then this workaround will be rejected on the OIDC discovery level.

Comment: @JanGaraj No, this works very well with OIDC discovery. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708121/16357334).

Comment: @sventorben it works only with libraries with poor discovery validation (I would say that is majority of libraries) - will this setup be working with libraries with more strict discovery validation, e.g. `go-oidc` or this kind of issue will be there https://github.com/coreos/go-oidc/issues/204 ?

Comment: Setting the frontend URL will also set the issuer in the well-known/openid-configuration response to frontend URL. It has a fix value which does not chane per request (see my answer) and therefore such an issue should not arise.

Comment: @sventorben IMHO you still don't see an issue. I would recommend to test it with app, which has proper OIDC discovery validation: configure custom frontend URL for the realm (e.g. `https://accounts.google.com`) and run `docker run -it --rm quay.io/gogatekeeper/gatekeeper:1.3.8 --listen 127.0.0.1:8080 --upstream-url http://127.0.0.1:80 --discovery-url https://KEYCLOAK/auth/realms/REALM --client-id CLIENTID`  It is an Impersonation attack: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#Impersonation

Comment: With your example you have intentionally misconfigured Keycloak. Of course, you will need to put the public URL (with a domain you own) of your Keycloak instance as frontend URL in production scenarios.