# keycloak + Kong API Gateway

Tags: token, keycloak, introspection, api-gateway, kong

We are using keycloak to handle authentication (client/secret) in our API Gateway.

The Kong api service uses konnect-managed-plugin to refer to keycloak to authenicate client credentials and return a bearer token.

Future calls to other endpoints use oauth2-introspection to verify the bearer token via keycloak introspection

I almost have this working however, when I authenticate via Kong api gateway, it returns a bearer token, but this token fails introspection.

If I auth straight to keycloak, the bearer token works for introspection.

eg

Token from:
http://kongapigateway.domain/getOAuthToken

- NOTE: We have not yet set up ssl on the kong api gateway

Returns:

```
{"access_token":"ey..ZiUQyw","expires_in":900,"refresh_expires_in":0,"token_type":"Bearer","not-before-policy":0,"scope":"email profile"}
```

Calling api endpoint in kong that uses introspection fails:
http://kongapigateway.domain/bookings

```
{
    "error_description": "The access token is invalid or has expired",
    "error": "invalid_token"
}
```

Direct call to keycloak introspection also fails:
[https://keycloak.domain/auth/realms/{Realms}/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect](https://keycloak.domain/auth/realms/%7BRealms%7D/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect)

```
{
    "active": false
}
```

However if I get token direct from keycloak server:
[https://keycloak.domain/auth/realms/{Realms}/protocol/openid-connect/token](https://keycloak.domain/auth/realms/%7BRealms%7D/protocol/openid-connect/token)

```
{"access_token":"eyJhb...4lT8w","expires_in":900,"refresh_expires_in":0,"token_type":"Bearer","not-before-policy":0,"scope":"email profile"}
```

The token works for both endpoints:
http://kongapigateway.domain/bookings and [https://keycloak.domain/auth/realms/{Realms}/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect](https://keycloak.domain/auth/realms/%7BRealms%7D/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect)

So why doesn't the introspection work for the token returned in the first scenario

Comment: Have you checked the content of the token using https://jwt.io/ for example ?

Comment: Thank. I checked the token and the token that fails has an ip address for the issuer server. The one that works has keycloak.domain for host. I assume this is the issue? Is there a way to configure issuing server in keycloak? Or in KONG?

Comment: Nevermind. Thank you Orel ! I was able to fix by setting Realm Frontend url to desired host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by setting Keycloak's frontend URL to your public URL. For details please refer to [my answer to another but similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70697745/keycloak-token-verification-fails-when-the-backend-is-running-in-a-docker-contai/70708121#70708121).