# Getting 401 Unauthorized when calling Quarkus app inside a Docker container with Keycloak authorization

Tags: cross-domain, keycloak, quarkus, docker-image

I have a client app running on  `localhost:4200`  (angular app) that gets resources from a Quarkus app( `localhost:8082` ). The authorization is done using  `Keycloak` .

The authorization works fine if I start both Angular & Quarkus apps on my localhost:
[image]

However, it does not work if I build a Docker image with my Quarkus app and run it inside a Docker container. Angular app still runs on my localhost, not inside a container:

[image]

My Quarkus application.properties:

```
quarkus.http.port=8082
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://${KEYCLOAK_HOST:localhost}:${KEYCLOAK_PORT:8081}/auth/realms/the-realm
quarkus.oidc.client-id=the-api
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=secret
quarkus.oidc.authentication.scopes=profile

quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:4200
quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS
quarkus.http.cors.headers=accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
quarkus.http.cors=true
```

Does this happen because localhost inside a container does not refer to my machine's localhost ? So this property will have no effect: `quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:4200` ? I tried using `quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://host.docker.internal:4200` but it did not work..

As a beginner, any advice is apreciated, thank you !

Comment: Where is your Keycloak running? Could be an issue with the issuer. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708121/16357334) and see if it works.

Comment: My Keycloak is running inside a docker container, setting `Frontend URL` to `http://localhost:8081/auth` for my realm fixed the problem. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to this.
I did as suggested above and read the interesting "more details" link which certainly helped me understand the issue, but the problem remained.

I eventually got it working and wanted to expand on the accepted answer above.

As mentioned in the answer, one needs to put the right value in the realm `Frontend URL` property. `Frontend URL` means "the Keycloak public url that your front end app uses to authenticate with".

So, in my case, I am using Keycloak 20.0.2 in a container on an internal network (`flowt-net`) so my Quarkus app could find it. I have a Vue 3 app to test the authentication.

This is a development test context so is not best practice re passwords, CORS, etc.

The Keycloak docker run:

```
docker run --name keycloak --net flowt-net -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin -p 8543:8080 -v keycloak:/opt/keycloak/data/h2 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest start-dev
```

The network is set as per `--net flowt-net`.

I also have a docker volume called `keycloak` to persist the built-in H2 database (`-v keycloak:/opt/keycloak/data/h2`)

For testing I started with the example app from https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect

The relevant Quarkus app `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.cors.origins=*

# See note below 
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://keycloak:8080/realms/quarkus

quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=MySecretFromKeycloakClientHere
quarkus.oidc.client-id=backend-service
```

The `http://keycloak:8080/realms/quarkus` refers to the url of the keycloak container named `keycloak` (`--name keycloak`) on the internal docker network, and the port `8080` is the KC internal port. ie as per `-p 8543:8080`.

The Quarkus app docker build:

```
./mvnw package;

docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm -t flowt-org-jvm .

docker run -i --rm --net flowt-net --name myquarkusapp -p 10000:8080 flowt-org-jvm
```

I am testing the dockerisation by using the JVM image for now.

The Vue app authenticates as below and I set it to run on localhost:3123 instead of localhost:8080 so I didn't get confused with the KC internal port number when I was trying to understand "who is who in the zoo".

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { vueKeycloak } from '@baloise/vue-keycloak'
import { vueAxios } from '@baloise/vue-axios'

createApp(App)
  .use(vueKeycloak, {
    initOptions: {
      flow: 'standard', // default
      checkLoginIframe: false, // default
      onLoad: 'login-required', // default
    },
    config: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8543/',
      realm: 'quarkus',
      clientId: 'frontend-app'
    }
  })
  .use(vueAxios, {
    // The Quasar app
    baseURL: '',
  })
  .mount('#app');
```

See https://github.com/baloise/vue-keycloak for more on vueKeycloak and vueAxios.

My Vue axios end point for the Quarkus app is eg `http://localhost:10000/api/users/me`

**Note**: for the more recent versions of Keycloak which were built using Quarkus, the authentication url is `http://localhost:8543/` **not** `http://localhost:8543/auth`.

Given the Keycloak image with `-p 8543:8080` you use your external / public port ie `8543` in this case.

In Keycloak admin for the Quarkus realm, the `Frontend URL` therefore needs to also be `http://localhost:8543/` in my case, and not `http://localhost:8543/auth` which some older SO posts suggest.

Theoretically that should have worked, but it didn't. I was still getting 401 errors.

The missing piece in the puzzle was that I needed to remove my existing Quarkus app and all its layers and **rebuild it from scratch**. Once I did that, it magically worked and my api calls in the Vue app started returning 200. Yay!

I hope that save someone some hours!

Go well,
Murray

Answer (score 1):

In the end it wasn't a CORS problem, as mentioned in the comments (thank you @sventorben!), the solution was to go into Keycloak realm settings and add `http://localhost:8081/auth` for `Frontend URL`:

[image]

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708121/16357334