# Keycloak token validation fails when app is running in docker container

Tags: spring, docker, kotlin, keycloak

I have some problems to verify a token when my application is running in docker. When I start it locally as a spring boot application, everything works fine.

I already read the thread here: [Keycloak token verification fails when the backend is running in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70697745/keycloak-token-verification-fails-when-the-backend-is-running-in-a-docker-container)
but the proposed solution (setting frontentUrl in the realm) doesn't work for me.

My enviroment:

- Spring Boot application + DB running with docker compose (using an external network)
- Keycloak container running with a different docker compose (using the same external network)

I can access Keycloak locally via postman (localhost:8180) and the app is available on localhost:8080.
I also can ping the keycloak from the app docker container with the container name.

No matter if I store the frontendUrl or not, when my local configuration of spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri is set to http://localhost:8180/realms/<realmname> and I run the app locally (without docker) the token is validated.
When I store a different url for frontendUrl (for example http://<keycloak-container-name>/) and the same in the application config (\http://<keycloak-container-name>/realms/<realmname>) it doesn't work. I tried it with and without the port (8180 or 8080) - nothing worked.

When I run the application in a docker container I can't validate the token no matter if I store the frontendUrl or not and which value I use. It seems like the application container can't access the keycloak container to validate the token even if the iss value in the token is the same as stored in the application config.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I have a vague recollection that Keycloak only allows insecure HTTP on certain private hostnames (like `localhost`) by default, but requires HTTPS otherwise, which might explain why accessing it doesn’t work in Docker.

Comment: Great idea. I set the realm setting "Require SSL" to NONE and it works! Thank you so much!