nginx with keycloak auth USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR invalid_token
I have 4 docker containers:

nginx 9000:80
keycloak 8080:8080
keycloak db
Simple API with one endpoint - / with methods POST | GET,  8000:80

I want to authorize requests to api through nginx.
nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<api_container>/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        auth_request /auth;
    }

    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://<keycloak_container>:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    }

    location = /auth_success {
        internal;
        return 204;
    }

    location = /auth_fail {
        internal;
        return 403;
    }
}

When send request to http://localhost:9000/ with header Authorization:<token_from_keycloak> I have error status code 401 and error in keycloak logs:
type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=dev, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=<SOME IP>, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
Question: How can i fix that error and make my auth flow work?
It looks like nginx send incorrect request to keycloak.
I tested such flow and it works:

Manually get keycloak access_token for user by POST request
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token
With request_body:

{
    "grand_type": "password",
    "client_id": "<my_client_id_from_keycloak>",
    "client_secret": "<my_client_secret_from_keycloak>",
    "username": "<my_username>",
    "password": "<my_user_password>"
}


Validate token by POST request
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<my_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
with header = Authorization: Bearer + <token_from_previous_step>
Result is 200 code with user data in body


Solved by setting Frontend URL = http://localhost:8080/auth in keycloak https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70697745/keycloak-token-verification-fails-when-the-backend-is-running-in-a-docker-contai
